# Iterate over directory and print some information

Tags: c, stat

I want to write a C program that takes as an argument the path to a folder and shows some info about the files it contains.

So far I have written this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char* dir_path = argv[1];
    char* dir_path_bar = strcat(dir_path, "/");
    DIR* dir = opendir(dir_path);

    for(struct dirent* entry = readdir(dir); entry != NULL; entry = readdir(dir)){
        printf("Next entry is %s\n", entry->d_name);
        char* entry_path = strcat(dir_path_bar, entry->d_name);
        printf("%s\n", entry_path);
        struct stat buf;
        stat(entry_path, &buf);
        printf("Its inode number is %s\n", entry->d_ino);
        printf("Its inode number is %s\n", buf.st_ino);
        printf("Its uid is %s\n", buf.st_uid);
        printf("Its size is %s bytes\n", buf.st_size);
    };
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Which compiles, but the `stat` call is giving me a SEGFAULT. What is going on?

Comment: You are calling `strcat` on one of the `argv` items. How do you know that the pointer has enough space for that? Instead, create a local buffer and copy `argv[1]` into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can't append to `argv[1]`. You can't keep appending to it inside the loop. And, you can't use `%s` to output numbers.

Here is your code with the bugs annotated and fixed [using `#if 0` to show the old code]:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *dir_path = argv[1];

// NOTE/BUG: argv[1] has a fixed size you can't append to it
#if 0
    char *dir_path_bar = strcat(dir_path, "/");
#else
    char dir_path_bar[PATH_MAX];
    strcpy(dir_path_bar,dir_path);
    strcat(dir_path_bar,"/");
#endif

    DIR *dir = opendir(dir_path);
#if 1
    if (dir == NULL) {
        perror(dir_path);
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    for (struct dirent *entry = readdir(dir); entry != NULL;
        entry = readdir(dir)) {
        printf("Next entry is %s\n", entry->d_name);

// NOTE/BUG: because you don't reset dir_path_bar, this just keeps appending
// to it
#if 0
        char *entry_path = strcat(dir_path_bar, entry->d_name);
#else
        char entry_path[PATH_MAX];
        strcpy(entry_path,dir_path_bar);
        strcat(entry_path,entry->d_name);
#endif

        printf("\n");
        printf("%s\n", entry_path);
        struct stat buf;

        stat(entry_path, &buf);

// NOTE/BUG: these need one or more of: %d/%ld/%lld (vs %s)
#if 0
        printf("Its inode number is %s\n", entry->d_ino);
        printf("Its inode number is %s\n", buf.st_ino);
        printf("Its uid is %s\n", buf.st_uid);
        printf("Its size is %s bytes\n", buf.st_size);
#else
        printf("Its inode number is %ld\n", entry->d_ino);
        printf("Its inode number is %ld\n", buf.st_ino);
        printf("Its uid is %d\n", buf.st_uid);
        printf("Its size is %ld bytes\n", buf.st_size);
#endif
    };

    closedir(dir);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "these need %d/%ld/%lld" --> that is unclear as `.d_ino, .st_ino, .st_uid, .st_size` are not certainly `long,long, int,long`  [ref](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/sys/types.h.html).  Some of those are some _unsigned_ members too.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- You're *appending* continuously to the input (`argv[1]`) argument which is undefined behaviour. You can't append to the strings of `argv`.
- Also printing integer values using `%s` which is undefined as well. `%`s expects a `char *` argument but you wanted to print integer values.

You can instead use a temporary buffer and pass it to [`stat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s dir\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    char* dir_path = argv[1];
    DIR* dir = opendir(dir_path);

    if (!dir) {
        perror("opendir");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(struct dirent* entry = readdir(dir); entry != NULL; entry = readdir(dir)) {
        char entry_path[PATH_MAX] = {0};
        int rc = snprintf(entry_path, sizeof entry_path, "%s/%s", dir_path, entry->d_name);

        if ( rc < 0 || rc >= sizeof entry_path) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Path truncated for '%s'\n", entry->d_name);
            continue;
        }
        printf("Next entry is: %s\n", entry_path);
        struct stat buf;
        if (stat(entry_path, &buf) == 0) {
            printf("Its inode number is %ju\n", (uintmax_t)entry->d_ino);
            printf("Its inode number is %ju\n", (uintmax_t)buf.st_ino);
            printf("Its uid is %jd\n", (intmax_t)buf.st_uid);
            printf("Its size is %jd bytes\n", (intmax_t)buf.st_size);
        } else {
            perror("stat");
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

I have also added some error checking.

Comment: I'd UV again for the wise use of `(uintmax_t)` with `entry->d_ino` (as likewise 3x other places.)

Comment: I've clean up prior comments.  With `snprintf()` robust error detection uses `int y = snprintf(p, sz, ...); if (y < 0 || y >= n)) error();`  Your `snprintf(...) >= (int) sz)` is OK but does not catch the rare encoding error, nor the rare situation where `(int) sz` lose information.

Comment: In general, good error handling unfortunately makes for longer less appealing code.  Too bad this answer was not accepted.

Comment: I agree (note that `y < 0` is not in standard C but POSIX). But I don't get why `(int) sz` truncation would be an issue because snprintf returns an `int`. Casting snprintf's return value to `size_t` has the opposite problem (e.g., snprintf returns a negative value).

Comment: Only addressing C, not POSIX:  "Thus, the null-terminated output has been
completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`."  C11 §7.21.6.5 3.  Testing for negative `y` _is_ because of the C standard.  In extreme case, if `sz` was `INT_MAX + 1`, `(int) sz` may become some negative  and incorrectly label `sprintf()` a failure.  "snprintf's return value to size_t has the opposite problem  (e.g., snprintf returns a negative value)" is not applicable because it is after the `y < 0` and so the `y >= n` cast/compare is not executed with negative `y`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186321/discussion-between-chux-and-usr).

Comment: I've [detailed some thoughts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54084570/2410359) about `snprintf()` based on our discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Not shown in the other 2 earlier answers is a nice avoidance of excessive copying.

When forming the `entry_path`, only the entry itself needs to be overwritten, not the entire string.  This becomes  valuable with a long pre-fixed directory string.

```
    dir_path_len = strlen(dir_path);
    if (dir_path_len >= PATH_MAX - 1) { return EXIT_FAILURE; } // too long

    char entry_path[PATH_MAX];
    strcpy(entry_path, dir_path);
    strcpy(entry_path + dir_path_len++, "/"); // Can use strcpy() here

    DIR *dir = opendir(dir_path);
    ...
    for (struct dirent *entry = readdir(dir); entry != NULL; entry = readdir(dir)) {
        printf("Next entry is %s\n", entry->d_name);

        entry_len = strlen(entry->d_name);
        if (dir_path_len + entry_len >= PATH_MAX) { 
            continue;
            // or 
            return EXIT_FAILURE; // too long
        }
        strcpy(path + dir_path_len, entry->d_name);  // strcpy(), not strcat()

        printf("\n%s\n", entry_path);

        struct stat buf;
        if (stat(entry_path, &buf) ...
        ...
```