# How to detect `snprintf` errors?

Tags: c, printf

```
int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

`snprintf()` nicely prevents overrunning the destination `s`.  Yet when the destination is insufficient for the complete result, how to detect that and other errors?

Is the following sufficient?.

```
char buf[11 + 10 + 1];
if (snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "Random int %d", rand()) >= sizeof buf) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Buffer too small");  // Maybe `int` was 64-bit?
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean *overrunning* rather than *overwriting*.  You can solve this sort of problem altogether using `asprintf`, which allocates the string on the heap.  You still need to check it worked (the underlying `malloc` can fail), but you needn't worry about inadequate buffer.  Disadvantages: you need to free the constructed string, additional time to allocate and deallocate space.

Comment: @PeretteBarella Note: `asprintf()` is not a standard C library function - even though is often available on various extended libraries.

Comment: tested, even the `GCC  -O1` flag will show the error. if not specified, then no error.

Answer (score 16):

This is part of [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  Additional answers are welcome.

> How to detect `snprintf` errors in C?

**Short answer**

Recall `snprintf()` returns an `int` to indicate the length of the stirng that would have been written or a negative value for an encoding error.

```
if ((size_t) snprintf(... ) >= sizeof buf) {
  error();
}
```

Pedantically, use the wider of `size_t` or `unsigned` cast, so better as:

```
int length_needed = snprintf(... );
if (length_needed < 0 || (unsigned) length_needed >= sizeof buf) {
  error();
}
```

---

**Testing for truncation**

Sometimes it is **very important** to detect a truncated string from `snprintf()`.  Lacking a test can lead to trouble:

```
char buf[13];
char *command = "format_drive";
char *sub_command = "cancel";  
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s %s", command, sub_command);
system(buf); // system("format_drive") leads to bye-bye data
```

---

**OK code**

A single test if the return value meets or exceeds the size of the destination array is *nearly* sufficient.

```
char buf[20];
if (snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "Random int %d", rand()) >= sizeof buf) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Buffer too small");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**Negative value**

> The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`.  C11dr §7.21.6.5 3

Robust code would directly check for a negative value for the rare *encoding error*.  `if (some_int <= some_size_t)` unfortunately is not sufficient as the `int` will be converted to a `size_t`. An `int` negative return value then becomes a large positive `size_t`.  This *usually* is far larger than the size of the array yet is not specified to be so.

```
// Pedantic check for negative values 
int length_needed = snprintf(... as above ...);
if (length_needed < 0 || length_needed >= sizeof buf) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Buffer too small (or encoding error)");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**Mis-match sign-ness**

Some compiler warnings whine about comparing integers of different sign-ness such as gcc's `-Wsign-compare` with `int` and `size_t`.  Casting to `size_t` seems reasonable.

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]

```
// Quiet different sign-ness warnings
int length_needed = snprintf(... as above ...);
if (length_needed < 0 || (size_t) length_needed >= sizeof buf) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Buffer too small (or encoding error)");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

**Pedantic**

C does not specify that the positive values of `int` are a sub-range of `size_t`.  `size_t` could be `unsigned short` and then `SIZE_MAX < INT_MAX`.   (I know of no such implementation.)  Thus a cast to `(size_t) some_int` could alter the value.  Instead, casting the positive return value to `unsigned` (`INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX` is always true) will not alter the value and will ensure the compare is done with the widest unsigned type between `unsigned`  and `size_t`.

```
// Quiet different sign-ness warnings
int length_needed = snprintf(... as above ...);
if (length_needed < 0 || (unsigned) length_needed >= sizeof buf) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Buffer too small (or encoding error)");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: I think that the remark "`size_t` could be `unsigned short`" should explicitly mention the implied assumption that `unsigned short` and `unsigned int` aren't the same.  That is, `SIZE_MAX`, `USHRT_MAX`, and `UINT_MAX` all being the equal isn't  outlandish, but the weird case would be a hypothetically pathological implementation where `SIZE_MAX < UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Answer amended per your suggestion.

Comment: This looks like it may be useful: https://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_snprintf_or_die